# General term for decreasing odd numbers.

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

We all are aware of the fact that the general from for representing odd numbers is-
$$2n+1\ or \ 2n-1\ \forall \ n \ \epsilon \ I$$
But with this type of general term, the value of the number increases when we increase $n$. I tried but I couldn't find a general term where as $n$ increases the value of number decreases and the number remains odd.
**Note:-** I am here not talking about anything like $-2n+1$ or $-2n-1$. In these cases as we increase the value of $n$ (Keeping $n$ positive), the value of number surely decreases but it becomes negative. What I am asking for here is such a general term in which we increase $n$, the number becomes positive for positive values but decreases if we increases n.


I feel I am not able to convey properly so I will try to explain with an example.
General term for series like-
$$n.......11,9,7,5,3,1$$
of form similar to $2n+1$ or $2n-1$

This may sound basic to many readers but I pondered over it for a long time but couldn't find such term. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: $11 - 2n$ where $n$ starts at $0$?

Comment: The 1st term of the series in not necessarily eleven, I am asking for a general formula here.

Comment: It can't both be positive for all large $n$ and decreasing.

Comment: N.b., the ellipsis ($\dots$) shouldn't be there. Once you get to $1$ you have to stop: there is no positive odd number less than $1$.

Comment: If you accept $n$ is a positive odd number. Then it is impossible. Because, largest positive integer doesn't exist. "Decreasing" implies we need largest positive integer, that must produce all odd positive integers, which is not possible.

Comment: @lonestudent Ah so this type of series can't be represented by a general term as we don't know the largest odd integer.

Comment: We don't know- I think this is not a correct approach. We say largest positive integer doesn't exist. Because, positive integers unbounded.

Comment: I'd rephrase your last comment, The problem is that you do not know where the sequence starts. There's no reason to talk about the (nonexistent) largest odd integer.

Comment: If the largest positive integer that you wanted to express was $2R-1$, then you could try $\max(2R+1- 2n, 1)~:~ n \in \Bbb{Z^+}.$

Comment: Hmm I got it, a threshold is necessary.

Comment: You are essentially asking for an infinite sequence that has no first element but a last element:  (infinite numbers at the "beginning")........., 9,7, 5,3, 1 (the end).  That is not how sequences work.  Sequences have a first time and are either finite or countably infinite but the are in sequential order starting from a first term.

Answer (score 1):

If the first therm of your sequence is $k$ then it is impossible for the sequence to contain the odd numbers greater than $k$, so no sequence will be able to cover all of them.

Answer (score 0):

> In these cases as we increase the value of n (Keeping n positive), the value of number surely decreases but it becomes negative. What I am asking for here is such a general term in which we increase n, the number becomes positive for positive values but decreases if we increases n.

By the well ordering principal any such representation will be finite.  The first term will be a positive value, call it, $M$ and every subsequent term would be less than $M$ and there are only $M$ such positive terms and $\frac {M+1}2$ such positive odd terms so you list can only be at most  $\frac {M+1}2$ terms long.

And such an example is easy to come up with.   $5197 - 2n$, for example will list $5197, 5195,5193,......, 9,7,5,3,1$.

....

BTW as practice in asking a *GOOD* question I think it's of tantamount importance that you actually *say* what you are asking.  If you didn't want negative values in the first place it was entirely *YOUR* responsibility to state that.  There is *nothing* in talking of a decreasing sequence of odd integers the implies negative values are not to be considered.

Nor for that matter that you want an infinite sequence.

(And in reading comments it sounds as though you wanted a sequence that includes *all* odd numbers, something *else* you did not indicate.   It never even occurred to me that that was your requirement.)